# Just started farcry3 and can't find crafting option in menu

Tags: far-cry-3

[image]

I just started farcry3 and can't find crafting option in menu i just keep killing ppl and skinning animals and i cant craft stuff ..

Do i need to do something to be able to craft?

Answer (score 3):

Crafting will unlock as you progress through the story and will be added under "skills". See this image for a full menu post-game (PC)

[image]

Comment: I dont see thos when my game starts 
 https://youtu.be/cNkpCLIDKj0

Comment: Not sure what you mean "this" especially in the context of the video. Like I said in my answer, you need to progress in the story. The video you linked in part 1 of a walkthrough so naturally he won't have the required progress yet. It's been a long while since I played FC3 but you'll unlock skills when you get your first "Tatau" which is a tattoo that appears during a cutscene. I think you unlock crafting at the same point.

Comment: The thing is , It seems like there is no story... I started the game via story mode/survivor, game should start with a video of the guys celebrating and flying and parachuting then getting captured and escape, at least that's what I saw on youtube, my game starts with me in a small camp and no one is around and when I go to map view, I see all the areas have fast travel icons and the objective is explore the map and find new missions! Is there anyway I can share a video of what's happening with me to you here?

Comment: What I mean by "this" in the video is the starting scene

Comment: Oh wow yes that is very weird. The game is totally supposed to start the way the YouTube video shows. Is the game downloaded digitally of bought on disc? I mean it's a bit of a stretch but I could see a disc being a demo or bootleg more likely than a digital version would be. Of course if disc, I don't know how / where you got it so these are just random thoughts.

Comment: Am i allowed to share vimeo video which 
I own?  https://vimeo.com/271301559?ref=em-share